# How to upgrade groovy-all from 2.4 to 2.5 when running in OSGi?

Tags: java, maven, groovy, osgi, pax-exam

I'm maintaining an open source library based partly on Groovy called [Rest Assured](http://rest-assured.io/). In the next version I'd like to upgrade the Groovy dependency from 2.4.x to 2.5.x. However when doing this I run into issues when running the OSGi tests. The tests are using [Pax Exam](https://ops4j1.jira.com/wiki/spaces/PAXEXAM4/overview) they typically look something like [this](https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/blob/master/examples/rest-assured-itest-java-osgi/src/test/java/io/restassured/test/osgi/XmlPathOSGiITest.java):

```java
@RunWith(PaxExam.class)
public class XmlPathOSGiITest {

    @Configuration
    public static Option[] configure() {
        return new Option[]
                {
                        mavenBundle("org.apache.servicemix.bundles", "org.apache.servicemix.bundles.hamcrest", "1.3_1"),
                        junitBundles(),
                        systemProperty("pax.exam.osgi.unresolved.fail").value("true"),
                        systemProperty("org.ops4j.pax.logging.DefaultServiceLog.level").value("INFO"),

                        /* Transitive dependencies needed in the Pax Exam container.
                        Some of these need to be wrapped because they are not available as OSGi bundles */
                        mavenBundle("org.apache.commons", "commons-lang3").versionAsInProject(),
                        wrappedBundle(mavenBundle().groupId("org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup").artifactId("tagsoup").versionAsInProject()),
                        wrappedBundle(mavenBundle("javax.xml.bind", "jaxb-api").versionAsInProject()),
                        wrappedBundle(mavenBundle("javax.activation", "activation").version("1.1.1")),
                        wrappedBundle(mavenBundle().groupId("org.codehaus.groovy").artifactId("groovy-all").version("2.5.6")),
                        wrappedBundle(mavenBundle("org.apache.httpcomponents", "httpclient").versionAsInProject()),
                        wrappedBundle(mavenBundle("org.apache.httpcomponents", "httpmime").versionAsInProject()),
                        wrappedBundle(mavenBundle("org.apache.httpcomponents", "httpcore").versionAsInProject()),

                        /* Rest Assured dependencies needed in the Pax Exam container to be able to execute the tests below */
                        mavenBundle("io.rest-assured", "json-path").versionAsInProject(),
                        mavenBundle("io.rest-assured", "xml-path").versionAsInProject(),
                        mavenBundle("io.rest-assured", "rest-assured").versionAsInProject(),
                        mavenBundle("io.rest-assured", "rest-assured-common").versionAsInProject()
                };
    }

    @Test
    public void getUUIDParsesAStringResultToUUID() {
        final String UUID_XML = "<some>\n" +
                "  <thing id=\"1\">db24eeeb-7fe5-41d3-8f06-986b793ecc91</thing>\n" +
                "  <thing id=\"2\">d69ded28-d75c-460f-9cbe-1412c60ed4cc</thing>\n" +
                "</some>";

        final UUID uuid = from(UUID_XML).getUUID("some.thing[0]");

        assertThat(uuid, Matchers.equalTo(UUID.fromString("db24eeeb-7fe5-41d3-8f06-986b793ecc91")));
    }
}
```

Running this test will cause an error:

```java
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 1.86 sec <<< FAILURE! - in io.restassured.test.osgi.XmlPathOSGiITest
getUUIDParsesAStringResultToUUID(io.restassured.test.osgi.XmlPathOSGiITest)  Time elapsed: 1.85 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.io.IOException: Error resolving artifact org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:jar:2.5.6: Could not find artifact org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:jar:2.5.6 in central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/)
        at org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.internal.AetherBasedResolver.resolve(AetherBasedResolver.java:626)
```

The point of interest is probably this line:

```java
wrappedBundle(mavenBundle().groupId("org.codehaus.groovy").artifactId("groovy-all").version("2.5.6")),
```

Everything was working fine when the Groovy was specified to use `version` 2.4.15. So my questions is:

How do I upgrade Groovy from 2.4 to 2.5 in an OSGi context when having depended on the `groovy-all` jar from 2.4 in past? And how do I reflect this in the test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that after choosing the correct artifacts, in this case groovy and groovy-json, you need [Apache Aries SPI Fy](http://aries.apache.org/modules/spi-fly.html) as well.

```
mavenBundle().groupId("org.apache.aries.spifly").artifactId("org.apache.aries.spifly.dynamic.bundle").version("1.2.1")
```

If you don't add that bundle, the groovy-json OSGi Fragment bundle does not get RESOLVED, without any hints about the cause in the logging.

Answer (score 2):

I think that starting from 2.5 version there is no single jar https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-8751

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a problem retrieving Groovy 2.5.6 from central. I am getting the same error trying to use Maven directly: `mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:3.1.1:get org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:jar:2.5.6`

Looking at the [server](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-all/2.5.6/) you can see that only docs and sources are available but not the JAR file. This is the case for all 2.5 releases of Groovy-all.

I assume the reason for this is that all 2.5 releases are just some sort of "meta artifact" without own code (therefore no JAR is available). The actual implementation is split into the following artifacts groovy-all depends on:

```
org.codehaus.groovy:groovy
org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-ant
org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-cli-commons
org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-cli-picocli
org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-console
org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-datetime
org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-docgenerator
org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-groovydoc
org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-groovysh
org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-jmx
org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-json
org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-jsr223
org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-macro
org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-nio
org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-servlet
org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-sql
org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-swing
org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-templates
org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-test
org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-test-junit5
org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-testng
org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-xml
```

Therefore for modifying your code you have to identify the groovy artifacts you really need and add them one by one to your code.